# Apache Ignite client is not able to compute hash code for string key

Tags: c#, ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite thin client (Apache.Ignite.dll 2.8.1) to create cache with a string key. When I try to insert record in cache I receive an exception:

*Failed to compute hash code for object 'dataservice:getdata:egd:viewmeta:positionfinancingdetail:653489822'"} at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryHashCodeUtils.GetComplexTypeHashCode[T](T val, Marshaller marsh, IDictionary`2 affinityKeyFieldIds)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryHashCodeUtils.GetHashCode[T](T val, Marshaller marsh, IDictionary`2 affinityKeyFieldIds)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.GetPartition[TKey](TKey key, Int32 partitionCount, IDictionary`2 keyConfiguration)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.GetAffinitySocket[TKey](Int32 cacheId, TKey key)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.DoOutInOpAffinity[T,TKey](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc, Int32 cacheId, TKey key, Func`3 errorFunc)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.DoOutInOpAffinity[T](ClientOp opId, TK key, TV val, Func`2 readFunc)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.Put(TK key, TV val) at HazelTree.DataService.Core.Caching.IgniteCacheTableClient.RegisterCache(String cacheName, Boolean isEmpty) in D:\projects\DataService\Core\Caching\IgniteCacheTableClient.cs:line 53 at HazelTree.DataService.Core.Caching.IgniteDataCache.DynamicCacheClient.<PutAllAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in D:\projects\DataService\Core\Caching\IgniteDataCache.cs:line 198    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()    at HazelTree.DataService.Core.Caching.IgniteDataCache.<GetOrAddAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in D:\projects\DataService\Core\Caching\IgniteDataCache.cs:line 70    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  at HazelTree.DataService.Core.CacheDataNode.d__4.MoveNext() in D:\projects\DataService\Core\Nodes\CacheDataNode.cs:line 37*
*

If I restart ignite server issue may dissapear time to time, but then it can appear during future restarts. Unfortunately I haven't reproduced the issue in Apache.Ignite.Examples.

Is there any simple root cause for the issue?
Are there any limitations on string keys in ignite?
Perhaps the issue is fixed in later releases?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug, here is the ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-14826

Will fix it ASAP and include in [upcoming 2.11 release](http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/Discussion-Apache-Ignite-2-11-Scope-Freeze-td52747.html)